# Combine and Sink - Wait for next value

Tags: swift, combine

I am listening to a value sent by a component, it can be .unknown, .granted and .denied.
If I get .unknown is there an elegant way to wait for another value with a timeout?

```
 let cancellable = permission.sink { status in
        switch status {
        case .unknown :
            // should wait for next value with a 1 second timeout
        case .granted:
            // do something
        case .denied:
            //show error
        }
    }.store(in &bag)
```

Comment: What's wrong with just doing nothing (`break`)? The closure would be called again the next time `permission` publishes something anyway.

Comment: Because sometimes not calling again, and then you should show an error message

Comment: Ah my bad - I completely ignored the "with a 1 second timeout" part. So if you don't get another value within one second, do you want the publisher to terminate? Also, is it ok if the next value is also another unknown?

Comment: No, I don’t want it to terminate. I just want to verify if I don’t get another non unknown value within that time period. Sometimes between state changes the publisher sends .unknown but immediately sends .granted. Other time it just send unknown and in this case if I don’t get the granted right after it means that I should show an error.